# how to use like clause in mysql to find grades

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my query

```
SELECT distinct(DESIG_NAME) 
FROM employees 
WHERE GRADE like ("L0007", "L0008", "L0009");
```

I want to find `grade` of `employee` in one single statement

grade are level e.g., level7, level8, etc something like this

Comment: Your problem description is not clear (actually confusing).

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` is not a function, and also you want `WHERE IN (...)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DESIG_NAME
FROM employees
WHERE GRADE IN ('L0007', 'L0008', 'L0009');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct(DESIG_NAME) FROM employees where GRADE like 'L0007' or like 'L0008' or like 'L0009'
```